# A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$abbrev

Tags: php

I encountered this error when I pressed the Search button and I search the title
The title and the date is showing fine on the table but not the abbrev and the professor any idea on what went wrong?

Here's my code:

View:

```
<?php

      foreach ($actor as $project ) {
echo generateTableRow($project);
 }

 function generateTableRow($project)

  {
  $projectUrl = base_url("show_project?id=$project->proj_id");
  $date = date('F d, Y (h:i A)', strtotime($project->date_uploaded));
  $abbrev = ($project->abbrev);
  $professor = ($project->professor);
  $tableRow =  '<tr>';
  $tableRow .= "<td><a href=\"$projectUrl\">$project->title</td>";
  //$tableRow .= "<td>$project->abbrev</td>";
  $tableRow .= "<td>$abbrev</td>";
  $tableRow .= "<td>$date</td>";
  $tableRow .= "<td>$professor</td>";
  $tableRow .= '</tr>';

  return $tableRow;
```

Model :

```
public function search_title($title){

        $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->from("projects_tbl");
        $this->db->like("title", $title);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query->num_rows() > 0 ){
            return $query->result();

        } else {

            return $query->result();
```

Controller :

```
 public function search_title(){

    $this->load->model("Learning_model");
    $title = $this->input->post('search');

    if(isset($title) and !empty($title)){

        $data['actor'] = $this->Learning_model->search_title($title);
        $data['links'] = '';
        $this->load->view('template/header1');
        $this->load->view('Learning/browse' , $data);
        $this->load->view('template/footer');

    } else {
        redirect($this->browse());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you render the view, `$project`s (items of the array `$actor`) are objects and those don't have a property named `abbrev`. Here the error you get (but that's quite obvious).

When your model generate `$actor`, `abbrev` and `professor` are not part of "actors" so either the table you fetch data from doesn't contain those columns or have different names.

Couldn't help more with the code/info provided. Hope it helps.